# Trying to pull data from one table to a field in another - Getting "The name does not exist in the current context" Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have 4 SQL tables: product, vendor, customer, and order.
I have created a table in c# that will allow users to create, read, update, and delete items from each table.

In the order table, I want to pull in data such as the Product Name, Price, Customer name, and vendor from the other tables.

The first one I am attempting is the ProductName and I would like the items in the name field from the product table show up as a dropdown in a field on the order table.  I thought I had it set up properly but the dropdown ID from my OrderForm.aspx file was giving an error and now seeing the ID from the OrderForm.aspx.cs file. I have named the dropdown and now it shows up when I load the page, but you cannot change the item or add it to the list.

I've tried moving the section around, assigning the dropdown to a variable to get it to find the dropdown ID and this has made the drop down available but the add button no longer works. I have commented out some of the things I've tried in the code below.

```
namespace VirtualStore

{
    public partial class OrderForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=rdw-etracsql01;Initial Catalog=SALES_KD;Integrated Security=True;";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateGridview();
                PopulateDropdown();
            }
            else
            {
               // PopulateTextFields();
            }

        }
        /* public void PopulateTextFields()
        {

            SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM product");
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                sqlCon2.Open();
            SqlDataReader listProductPrices;
            listProductPrices = sql.ExecuteReader();
            ds = listProductPrices;
        } */
        void PopulateDropdown()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon2.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM product", sqlCon2);
                da.Fill(ds);
            }            
                DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("DropProductNameFooter");

                //  myDDL.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ProductName"].ToString();
                //  myDDL.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString(); 
                myDDL.DataSource = ds; //.Tables[0];
                myDDL.DataTextField = "ProductName";
                myDDL.DataValueField = "ProductID";
                myDDL.DataBind();
            TextBox ProductPrice = (TextBox)gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductPriceFooter");

            string ProductID = myDDL.DataValueField.ToString();
            ProductPrice.Text = ds.Tables[0].Select("ProductID=" + ProductID)[0]["ProductPrice"].ToString(); 

        }
        void PopulateGridview()
        {
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [order]", sqlCon);
                sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            }
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvOrder.DataSource = dtbl;
                gvOrder.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
                gvOrder.DataSource = dtbl;
                gvOrder.DataBind();
                gvOrder.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                gvOrder.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                gvOrder.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dtbl.Columns.Count;
                gvOrder.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found ...!";
                gvOrder.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;

            }
        }


        protected void gvOrder_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
                {
                    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        sqlCon.Open();
                        string query = "INSERT INTO [order] (ProductName, ProductPrice, ProductQuantity, CustomerID, TotalPrice, OrderDate) VALUES (@ProductName, @ProductPrice, @ProductQuantity, @CustomerID, @TotalPrice, @OrderDate)";
                        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", (gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductNameFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", (gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductPriceFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductQuantity", (gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProductQuantityFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", (gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerIDFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPrice", (gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtTotalPriceFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", (gvOrder.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOrderDateFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        PopulateGridview();
                        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "New Record Added";
                        lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put a break point after da.Fill(ds);  Then hover on ds and select down arrow and then DataSet Visualizer.  The form will have a pull-down of all the tables in the dataset.  See if you are getting any data.

Comment: and let's add the obligatory [don't use addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)